# How can I randomly obtain a specific number of records, lets say 100, and then order them by created at DESC in rails?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have tried below:

`products = Product.order("RANDOM()").limit(100).order("created_at DESC")`

But this is not in order of created_at. Instead, it is still random. I also know that this can be done by converting the Active Record collection into an array, and then ordering it, but for speed purposes, I would prefer not to do that.

Comment: `.reorder("created_at DESC")` is what you are looking for. Otherwise it uses the second order by after the first.

Comment: @dbugger But `#reorder` complete replaces whatever `ORDER BY` clause is already there so `.reorder('created_at desc')` will throw away the `.order('random()')`.

Comment: might need to do it in two statements -- grab the random records and reorder that set

Comment: @dbugger Or use a derived table or subquery to grab 100 random records.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it inside the database then you could use a derived table:

```
Product.from(Product.order(Arel.sql('random()')).limit(100), :products)
       .order(created_at: :desc)
```

that will use SQL (more or less) like this:

```
select products.*
from (
    select products.*
    from products
    order by random()
    limit 100
) products
order by created_at desc
```

You need the second `:products` argument to `#from` to convince the `Product` model that the derived table has the same structure as the `products` table.

Alternatively you could use a subquery:

```
Product.where(id: Product.order(Arel.sql('random()')).limit(100))
       .order(created_at: :desc)
```

That will use SQL like this:

```
select products.*
from products
where id in (
    select id
    from products
    order by random()
    limit 100
)
order by created_at desc
```

The results will be the same as the derived table version but subqueries tend to be slower; of course, checking the query plans is advisable if you're worried about performance.

Both of them grab your 100 random rows and then order those random rows by `created_at`. I'd probably go with the first version but, with `limit 100`, the performance difference probably depends more on how the `order by random() limit 100` is handled than the derived table versus a subquery.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I am going to research more now into "Arel". Thank you again.

Comment: Careful with AREL, it can be cumbersome to use IMO. I'm using `Arel.sql('...')` here because newer versions of ActiveRecord will complain about strings passed to some methods so things like `Arel.sql('random()')` are needed to avoid noisy deprecation warnings.